# Need to write a unix script to FTP one .dat file

Tags: unix, unixodbc

I am new to unix (KSH) and I need to write a unix script to FTP one .dat file from one server location to another server location. Kindly  help to write such code.

"From- server A, Location - vic/folder/day.dat
TO - Server B, Location - sam/folder"

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to take a time to learn use of [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) command and [scripting](http://www.well.ox.ac.uk/~johnb/comp/unix/ksh.html). Wikipedia's expect page has a lot of samples about how to use it.